# Random forest for tensors

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, tensor

Say we have have input tensor $X \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N \times P}$ and output tensor $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N \times K}$, and we aim to build a Random Forests model $Y = f(X)+ \epsilon$.

Fixing $T=1$ gives the multivariate Random forests, which is already implemented in sklearn's version of Random Forests. But $T>1$ is more complicated. I guess you could run a multivariate Random Forests on for each $t \in 1,\ldots,T$. However, I have neither seen any theory nor codes for tensor Random Forests.

Therefore, is it currently possible to run Random Forests on Tensors/Multidimensional arrays? Would appreciate some article references if it is possible.

Comment: Could you explain the point of factoring the dimensions of the two spaces into $T\times N\times P$ *etc* instead of just calling them (say) $m$ and $n$?  There doesn't seem to be anything relevant about calling these spaces of "tensors" because you don't invoke or rely on any of the tensor properties apart from being real vector spaces.

Comment: @whuber: I refer to tensors as multidimensional arrays, and actually nothing else. So this, the two spaces are just real vector spaces. To exemplify, imagine $T$ time periods, $N$ individuals with $P$-dimensional vector of covariates for each individual and at each point in time. I would like to map this $P$ into $K$, taking into account the variation across both $T$ and $N$. Is that more clear?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear at all, because there is nothing in your question that indicates what "map this $P$ into $K$" might possibly mean.  You posit--perhaps a little too abstractly--a completely general function $f$ with no restrictions.  Perhaps you haven't yet included all the assumptions you want to make?  This is a danger of formulating a problem abstractly.  You can deal with it by clarifying your question and making it absolutely correct and/or by supplying a context to help us understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: It's really a standard setup: I have multidimensional input data $X$ and multidimensional output data $Y$ with dimensions specified above. I would like to train a Random Forests regressor that takes $X$ as input and predicts $Y$. Is that possible with dimensions $T \times N \times P$, instead of a "normal" setting, where input data have dimensions $N \times P$.

Comment: There's absolutely no difference.  Just write $N^\prime=T\times N$ and your problem becomes the normal setting with dimensions $N^\prime\times P$ and $N^\prime\times K.$

Comment: For clarity, if T=2 would this mean an input feature is a set of matrices rather than a set of scalars as in the normal case (T=1)?